# Altium Wire vs. Bus entry

Tags: schematics, altium

I have following situation in [Altium Designer](http://www.altium.com/):
[image: Bus]
Now, `AUDIO_INPUT_SELECT[0..3]` are connections to [Bus](http://www.altium.com/documentation/15.1/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-Bus((Bus))_AD), made using [Wire command](http://www.altium.com/documentation/15.1/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-Wire((Wire))_AD). However, after researching `Altium`, I've stumbled upon [Bus Entry command](http://www.altium.com/documentation/15.1/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-BusEntry((Bus+Entry))_AD) and the question is, do I have to change these `Wire` entities to `Bus Entry` entities or not and if I must, how do I *transform* `Wires` to `Bus Entries` in most elegant way? I know I can delete `Wire` and place instead of it `Bus Entry`, but I have several such connections and I want to know the most elegant path of executing such task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect wires directly to a bus; bus entries are not required.

A bus entry allows you to connect to both sides of the bus without the wires from both sides being shorted together.